# Jess - Add Facts with Random Function

Tags: jess

I am making a Tetris game and I want to know how can I add points to my facts.

```
 (deftemplate point
 (slot i(type INTEGER))
 (slot j(type INTEGER)))

 (defglobal ?*LINES* = 24)
 (defglobal ?*COLUMNS* = 12)

 (deffacts initial
 (piece 0))

 (defrule choosePiece   
 =>
 (bind ?y (mod (random) 7)) //there are 7 pieces in Tetris game
 (assert (piece ?y)))
```

I have a Random rule choosePiece and if the result of that rule is 1 I want to add one square to my facts in coordinates (1,6) (1,7) (2,6) (2,7), if it is 2 I want to add a T. How can I make this and then create a rule that allows me to modify the coordinates of those facts to move those pieces. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Although you certainly *could* implement this, it would be difficult and messy, and at the end of the day, pointless. Jess would be far better suited to writing a bot that *played* Tetris; I'd implement the Tetris game itself in Java.